Why is there a "two way handshake" with Stripe PaymentIntents?
https://docs.stripe.com/api/payment_intents/create

Creates a PaymentIntent object.
After the PaymentIntent is created, attach a payment method and confirm to continue the payment. Learn more about the available payment flows with the Payment Intents API.

I was reading that, and it looks like you have to do two POST requests if I'm not mistaken. Why can't we just do one POST request? I asked ChatGPT, and it said security purposes, but I just wanted to confirm.

For security purposes.

Some of this is conjecture, but I'm confident enough to post it as a response.
It has to do with how payment method collection and Payment Intent creation cannot be made using the same approach.

Stripe only officially* allows you to collect payment method data from the client (with confirmPayment, createPaymentMethod, etc.). This is for security / PCI compliance reasons.
The Payment Intent cannot be created from the client - if it could, bad actors could manipulate the client to change anything about your Payment Intent - e.g. the amount.

Because the Payment Intent creation and payment method collection have to be made on back and front ends respectively, you have to make two calls.
*I mentioned "officially". Privately, Stripe supports MOTO flows, which allows you to pass raw payment method details directly from the backend.
https://support.stripe.com/questions/mail-order-telephone-order-(moto)-transactions-when-to-categorize-transactions-as-moto
This flow requires you to have a PCI compliant server and prove it with Stripe.
I don't have access to the documentation on how to integrate MOTO, but I would suspect that because all of it can be done serverside, you could perform a single call for that flow.

If you have a Payment Method already created, you can include it here in the Payment Intent's creation request. If you also specify confirm: 'true' as mentioned here, and off_session: 'True' as mentioned here, the confirmation step happens without any additional API calls.
This means there will be 1 API request in total to create, attach, and confirm the Payment Intent.

That's true - only if you don't count the creation of the payment method as the another POST call though ;)

That also depends. For example, if you create a Payment Intent and pass it into the Payment Element to collect payment method details, you would have one server-side API call, and a few automatic client-side API calls, but your system would only need to explicitly call the API once for the Payment Intent creation. Everyone else would happen in the browser.
